# Can't dispatch action after failure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux

I implemented authentication on my app, the problem is when I try to login after failure, for example, if it is wrong password..

Here is the sign in function:

```
export const signIn = data => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ 
    type: SIGN_IN
    }) 
  fetch(API_URL+'/login', { 
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
   body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  } else {
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  }
}).then((responseJson) => {
      dispatch({
          type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, payload: responseJson
        }),
        localStorage.setItem("token", 'Bearer '+responseJson.token)
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(responseJson.user))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
          type: SIGN_IN_FAILED, payload: error
        })  
    });
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What happens after the failure?

Comment: Can't try to login again, doesn't dispatch login action..

Comment: you need to be more clear. what _exactly_ does not work, and where. explain exactly how we could reproduce.

Comment: I type wrong password, it dispatches login, login failed action, then if I try to type correct password, I click the button, it doesn't dispatch actions..